# groups and files in XCode vs. project folders in Finder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I still can't get the idea that when I create a new Group in XCode, and build the project, and then return back to finder and notice that the group does not exist but any file to be created under this group will appear in the project's directory in finder but that file is alone without being under any group.

(note: I'm not talking about this directory: /Users/*username*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/*uuid*/...)

1) can anyone explain why project's directory hierarchy in finder is different from the project's directory hierarchy in XCode ?
2) how can I make the two hierarchies looks like exactly the same between XCode and Finder? so when I create a new Group in future I can see it in finder.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently you cannot see the group you create in `Xcode` in finder. Its just a logical entity for you to organise your projects in a better way. Assuming you will be using xcode to make all the changes `(including version control)` you can use that categorisation and make sense out of it in Xcode.

However you always have the option of creating a folder in finder(`your project workspace`) and create files and save them in that folder using Xcode. This is particularly helpful for viewing organized code while browsing through the file system. Also you can group files into folders which you can then use across projects.

So basically it boils down to what your use case is. As for me i am happy using xcode. I usually create a directory to hold images and copy directories for libraries into my project folder so that there is `clean organisation` in the file  system too.

Comment: Praveen, thanks for your answer, for your second paragraph above, how can that be done excatly, like this: 1) i create folder in finder. 2) return to xcode and refresh the project 3) i should see that folder inside xcode and then start adding files into it ? I really saw many projects that have both directory hierarchies look like exactly the same, that's why i need to know how to do it

Comment: one problem with organizing images is that they end up in folders in the bundle and [UIImage imageNamed:] cannot load them

Answer (score 5):

Another helpful method is after you create the group in Xcode, but before you put files in it, check the File Inspector pane on the right with the group selected. Make sure Location is set **Relative to Group** and then click on the folder icon below that. This will bring up a Finder window. Then, make a directory with the same name, and click **Choose**. Now, anything you put in that group will go in that folder of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is that you make the require folder in Finder, then go to Xcode. In navigator, right click and select "Add files to" option, add the that folder. It will be added to your navigator as well. Now whatever you add to that group, it will be automatically added to your folder in finder as well.